# Relación entre tres tablas Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Buenos días como siempre tengo problemas con las relaciones. Tengo tres tablas y una de ellas hace de pivote.
Lo que quiero sacar una iteración de las categorías a la que pertenece el articulo, en la iteración de articulos.

**Mi tabla `articles`**

| id | titulo | foto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nombre noticia 1 | foto.jpg |
| 2 | nombre noticia 2 | foto.jpg |

**Mi tabla `category_blogs`**

| id | valor | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nutrition | nutrition |
| 2 | Training | training |

**Mi tabla `enlaza_categorias`**

| id | id_category | id_article |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

**Esta es la consulta en mi controlador:**

```
$noticias = articles::where('destacado', 0)->where('estado', 1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(8);
```

**Luego itero los articulos en mi vista**

```
@foreach ($noticias as $item)
.....
<div>
  //Aquí quiero sacar los nombres de la categoría
  @foreach ($item->categorias as $item2)
     <span>{{ $item2->id_category }}</span>
  @endforeach
</div>
.....
@endforeach
```

---

**Modelo `articles`**

```
protected $table = 'articles';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function categorias()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EnlazaCategoria', 'id_article');
    }
```

**Modelo `categoryBlog`**

```
class categoryBlog extends Model
{
    //Lo tengo vacio
}
```

**Modelo `EnlazaCategoria`**

```
protected $table = 'enlaza_categorias';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function categorias()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\categoryBlog', 'id');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si la relación es de *muchos a muchos*, entonces:

- Tus modelos `Articles` y `categoryBlog` deben tener una relación declarada del tipo [**`belongsToMany`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure)
- Inicialmente la tabla intermedia llamada: `enlaza_categorias` *no requiere de un modelo asociado* y si lo vas a emplear entonces [debes apegarte a lo que indica Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)

Una vez dicho lo anterior, podemos entonces:

1. Declarar las relaciones en cada modelo como fue indicado:

Modelo **articles**

```
public function categoriasBlogs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(categoryBlog::class, 'enlaza_categorias', 'id_article', 'id_category');
}
```

Modelo **categoryBlog**

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(articles::class, 'enlaza_categorias', 'id_category', 'id_article');
}
```

2. Ahora la consulta:

Hacemos una *carga* de las [relaciones asociadas a los artículos](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) pasando como argumento el nombre de la relación en el modelo `articles`

```
articles::whereDestacado(0)->whereEstado(1)->with('categoriasBlogs')->get();
```

*Es importante aclarar que para esta respuesta yo no consideré el uso de un modelo para la tabla intermedia*